# Check boxes contradicting each other

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox

I have a project that is "almost" done. I've gotten a ton of help here and I'm hoping I'll be able to finalize this project soon. I have a form with checkboxes that represent different attributes for 3 different items. As a user checks a specific checkbox I have whichever item that it does not correspond to hide, as well as any attribute that does not go with the one that was checked becomes disabled and the text color turns a light grey. So the only boxes that would still be active would be the ones that go together for said item.

I can get that all to work just fine (I think). But there are a few attributes that correspond to more than one item. If you look at my example (link provided)

If you check the 'Economy' chekcbox only 1 grey box 'Bernini' is displayed and a lot of other checkboxes become disabled, which is correct. Un-check it and everything is enabled and visible again.

If you check the 'Tape-in Bottom Rail' checkbox 2 grey boxes 'Bernini & Picasso' are displayed which is also correct as that attribute 'Tape-in Bottom Rail' applies to both. Un-check it and everything is enabled and visible again.

The issue I have is, IF you check both the 'Economy' & 'Tape-in Bottom Rail' then Un-check either of them, the wrong attributes become enabled and the visible grey boxes no longer correspond correctly.

I though I should use an 'else if' or another 'if' statement but if so I have not figured out how to get it to work correctly.

Here is the JS I'm using  so far, this is for only 1 of the functions.

```
function bannerBernini() {
if (document.checkForm1.att_2.checked || document.checkForm1.att_5.checked || document.checkForm1.att_6.checked || document.checkForm2.att_9.checked || document.checkForm2.att_15.checked || document.checkForm3.att_23.checked)
{
    var berninis = document.querySelectorAll('.picasso, .matisse, .picasso-matisse');
    for (var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) {
    berninis[i].style.color="#d1d1d1";}
    var not_bernini = document.querySelectorAll('#att_3, #att_10, #att_11, #att_13, #att_14, #att_16, #att_17, #att_18, #att_19, #att_20, #att_21, #att_22, #att_24');
    for (var j = 0; j <  not_bernini.length; j++){
    not_bernini[j].disabled=true;}
    document.getElementById("Picasso").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
}
else
{
    var berninis = document.querySelectorAll('.picasso, .matisse, .picasso-matisse');
    for(var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) {
     berninis[i].style.color="";}
    var not_bernini = document.querySelectorAll('#att_3, #att_10, #att_11, #att_13, #att_14, #att_16, #att_17, #att_18, #att_19, #att_20, #att_21, #att_22, #att_24');
    for (var j = 0; j <  not_bernini.length; j++){
    not_bernini[j].disabled=false;}
    document.getElementById("Picasso").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="";
}}
```

Here is the sample which I hope makes sense:

http://jsfiddle.net/g_borg/48uhn/1/

Thanks in advance for any assistance. I know some will say I should use jQuery, I would but as this is my 1st time trying to code with javascript and I'm not familiar with jQuery I'd prefer to try to keep this where I still understand the code.

Comment: _"I have a for of checkboxes..."_ um, what?

Comment: Make sure that when a checkbox becomes unticked, you first check which ones are still ticked before enabling boxes again.

Comment: This is a good place for `data-*` attributes. Add the relationships to an attribute and when unchecking a checkbox filter the affected checkboxs

Comment: Also a good idea to learn about the ternary operator. I just halved your function here http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zzscL/

Comment: Thank you folks for the help. @DylanMeeus that is what I though I was missing, as it doesn't know what is still checked, but I'm unsure how to do that correctly. Would I have to set another variable = to those unchecked?

Comment: @megawac I'm not understanding what data-* is referring to.

Comment: @mplungjan That looks much cleaner than what I had, but I would still need to do this in an if else statement correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My code did not FIX your logic problem, but only halved the code you have to look at. No else inside if the two selectors are correct

Comment: Specify the relationships of checkboxs in html5 data attributes and filter them down when you uncheck a checkbox. See http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/